# Android - One more "Accessing objects from a different thread"

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a question about accessing objects on the main thread from another thread. There seems to be a lot of information about it online with techniques to do that but everything I found applies to accessing Views on the UI thread. It may be that all those techniques also apply for objects other than View but I would just like to make sure.

For my concrete example I have a custom `BluetoothDeviceConection` class I wrote and contains functions like `connect`, `closeConnection`, `write` and so on. So functions for managing a connection to a specific `BluetoothDevice` which is passed as a parameter to `BluetoothDeviceConection`'s constructor. On my main thread I create three `BluetoothDeviceConection` objects for three devices. Now I want to connect to all three devices.

My idea is to send the `BluetoothDeviceConection` object of a device to a new thread, let it connect to that device and write data to it, thereby manipulating / modifying / accessing the passed `BluetoothDeviceConection` object. To make this thread safe every`BluetoothDeviceConection` object would be created with the `volatile` keyword.

Is that the correct way to go?

I am doing a similar thing with a TimerTask in which I call an "outside" function marked as `synchronized` and everything works fine.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `volatile` does not guarantee thread safeness by itself. `volatile` only tells compiler this value can be changed from multiple threads so it doesn't apply optimizations based on static code analysis. If you want it to be thread-safe, you need to use `synchronized` as you said for `TimerTask` or other methods (locks, semaphores, mutexes...) to make sure only one thread is accessing it at any given time.

I also suggest that instead of passing the `BluetoothDeviceConection` as a parameter to other classes, you wrap this object inside another class and write thread-safe methods for manipulating it.

Comment: Thank you. This will then be the way I will take.

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example of what you mean by making a new (wrapper) class in which I should "write thread-safe methods for manipulating it"? Is this as simple as adding the `synchronize` keyword in front of each method? Thanks.

Comment: That highly depends on how you're going to be accessing that BT connection and how you design the wrapper methods.

Comment: I plan on accessing it from an AsyncTask. As for the design of methods I don't really know what you mean. I followed Android Developer's guides on using Bluetooth but structured the code given there a bit by putting bits of code in its own functions.

Comment: I see no usage of `BluetoothDeviceConection` at the [BT guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Answer (score 0):

Same as with TimerTask your own class will work fine